# Setting puppeteer viewport to null doesn't change viewport

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, viewport

I am using puppeteer and I am setting the defaultViewPort param to null, however it doesn't change the actual viewport when chromium (or chrome, as I have changed it to be) is launched

`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, executablePath: 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', defaultViewPort: null, });`

Does anyone know why this isn't working for me?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The issue in this case seems to be a typo: `defaultViewPort` -> `defaultViewport`

So a fixed version would be:

```js
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
      headless: false, 
      executablePath: 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', 
      defaultViewport: null, 
    });
```

Note that setting the `defaultViewport` option to `null`, will prevent Puppeteer from setting it's own default value, and just use the default browser view port.

If you want to change the viewport size to some other value, you could for example do:

```js
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1280,
    height: 1080,
  })
```